# How to update config file with a new section of type NameValueSectionHandler at runtime?

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

suppose I have the following config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="sampleGroup">
   <section name="sampleSection1" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>
 </sectionGroup>

 <sampleGroup>
  <sampleSection1>
   <add key="key1" value="False" />
   <add key="key2" value="True" />
  </sampleSection1>
 </sampleGroup>

</configuration>
```

I need to insert a new section of the same type (nameValueSectionHandler) at runtime.
System.Configuration.Sections.Add(string name, ConfigurationSection section) method is expecting a configurationSection object so I cannot use that.

Comment: You could read the config file as XML and modify it from there. Be aware though, config is read at application start-up, i think you will have to recycle your app domain to load your changes.

Comment: I figured it out. You have to create a section of type DefaultSection and set the SectionInformation.Type as NameValueSectionHandler.